# Is it possible to non-recursively remap a command?

Tags: command-line, functions, plugin-fugitive, user-commands

So Fugitive defines `:Glog`. This is, apparently, aliased to a call to the script-local `s:Log()` function (according to `:command Glog`.)

My muscle-memory has been using `glog` at the command-line, for years, to invoke my custom git-log TUI; and I'd really like to remap the `:Glog` command to a different tool ([Gitv](https://github.com/gregsexton/gitv), specifically); but I'd like to retain Fugitive's available quickfix-list-based-log-navigation for special circumstances.

Is there any way for me to *remap* a call to a script-local function, like that? Or am I doomed to overwrite Fugitive's pre-defined `:Glog` and never have access to it, if I want it back?

Comment: Overwriting the command should be feasible; retaining the old behavior, much less so imo. Frankly i’d set up a dedicated mapping for invoking gitv, perhaps using `<leader>`, and adjust by using it. Muscle memory is awesome, but surprisingly adaptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it's possible to redefine `:Glog` without losing access to the script-local function.

However, bearing in mind your muscle memory is for `glog`, not `Glog`, I propose another approach:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> glog (getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdpos() == 5) ? 'Gitv' : 'glog'
```

This abbreviation will convert your `:glog` commands into `:Gitv` commands, leaving `:Glog` intact for when you need it.

Comment: Bahhah, that’s beautifully evil. Excellent!